# JObject contains a C# keyword - how to access it?

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I am using the JQuery QueryBuilder plugin on my site, which compiles it's data into JSON. On the server side code, I take the JSON that is returned from the plugin and parse it into a dynamic variable. The problem is, one of the keys is "operator", and the word operator is a c# keyword. I've tried using _operator, __operator, but these do not work. Any idea how I can access the value of the key "operator"?

For example, here is the JSON that I am working with (simplified, of course):

```
[{
     "id":"ABC",
     "value":"test",
     "operator":"equal"
}]
```

And here is the server side C# code

```
dynamic json = JObject.Parse(model.pJson);
foreach (var item in json.rules) {
     string id = item.id;    
     string value = item.value;
     string _operator = item.operator; // HERE IS THE PROBLEM! I cannot type item.operator because operator is a keyword
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `@` to use a keyword as an identifier, so this should work:

```
string _operator = item.@operator;
```

Alternatively, you may well find that indexer access would be fine:

```
string _operator = item["operator"];
```

Comment: I would guess that the former would be faster, as the latter requires some sort of dictionary lookup into item.

Comment: @Neil: It's `dynamic`.  They will both be equally slow.

Comment: @SLaks, I didn't spot that.  I suppose I should rephrase my statement to ask which one is the slowest :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try `item["operator"]`, using it as a dictionary.